# elasticsearch 1.1.1 rails 4 and ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I am using searchkick 0.7.1 to generate an elasticsearch 1.1.1 index on a server. Worked fine on my laptop. Now, I ran the index process on the server and it seems to completes, but the index doesn't get saved. I thought this was a memory issue and increased the ram. There are 800k records totaling about 300 megs in size. The server has several gigs of disk space free. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

```
elasticsearch.log:
    [2014-04-23 16:04:53,529][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Decay II] [products_development_20140423160453291] creating index, cause [api], shards [5]/[1], mappings [_default_]
    [2014-04-23 16:04:58,282][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Decay II] [products_development_20140423160453291] update_mapping [product] (dynamic)
    [2014-04-23 16:05:06,763][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [Decay II] [gc][young][101][3] duration [3.6s], collections [1]/[4.4s], total [3.6s]/[3.7s], memory [113.2mb]->[35.9mb]/[1007.3mb], all_pools {[young] [92mb]->[603.5kb]/[133.1mb]}{[survivor] [16.6mb]->[13.7mb]/[16.6mb]}{[old] [4.6mb]->[21.6mb]/[857.6mb]}
    [2014-04-23 16:54:16,015][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Decay II] [products_development_20140423134717640] deleting index
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Figured this out from prior posts. ENV in ruby wasn't set correctly for production.

This worked fine:

```
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RACK_ENV=production searchkick:reindex:all CLASS=Product
```